# Eslint with Nuxt3 auto-import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, nuxtjs3

Seems very basic but I can't find anywhere an eslint setup that works with Nuxt3 [auto-import](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports), to avoid [`no-undef`](https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-undef) errors. I'm not using typescript.

I tried the following packages: `@antfu/eslint-config`, `plugin:nuxt/recommended`, `@nuxt/eslint-config`, `@nuxtjs/eslint-config`, `@nuxt/eslint-config-typescript`, with no luck so far.

The only thing that works for now is setting each reference in .eslintrc `globals`...

Comment: You can use [explicit imports](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/concepts/auto-imports#explicit-imports) to avoid this problem. Implicit identifiers (whether global or scoped) are historically a common source of bugs — ESLint is trying to help you here.

Comment: Maybe, but Nuxt encourages using auto-imports, so you'd expect there to be a recommended solution.

Comment: There is now an experimental cli tool that works pretty well, I tried it on Nuxt3 and Vue project as well. It will install required packages, update you eslint config and even .vscode settings, if that is what you're into.

Simply run `npx @antfu/eslint-config@latest`.

Read more on [antfu/eslint-config](https://github.com/antfu/eslint-config).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I only use the following packages:

```
"@antfu/eslint-config": "^0.42.0"
"eslint": "^8.49.0"
```

and in VSCode, I have installed extensions:

```
dbaeumer.vscode-eslint
vue.volar
```

and my .eslintrc.js:

```
module.exports = {
  extends: [
    '@antfu',
  ],
};
```

and my .vscode/settings.json:

```
{
    "editor.formatOnSave": false,
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
        "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    },
    "eslint.options": {
        "extensions": [
          ".js",
          ".vue"
        ]
    },
}
```

This should accomplish what you're looking for.

NOTE: You ***do*** have to - whether you are using Typescript or not - run `nuxt dev` at least once to have Nuxt generate types internally inside `.nuxt` for auto-imports to work and allow Volar + ESLint to function properly.

Also, [ensure that Volar is running in Takeover mode](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/overview.html#volar-takeover-mode).

Comment: savior!! works with the @antfu you linked, not with the (not that) older one I was using, thanks.