# How do I get Eslint to recognize nuxt auto-import functions?

Tags: node.js, vue.js, nuxt.js, eslint, nuxt3

I have a new Nuxt 3 project in which I am using functions that are auto-imported by Nuxt such as 'useCookie', 'useRouter', 'ref', etc.. The functions are working as intended when I run the app, but Eslint marks them all as undefined. Is there a way to get Eslint to recognize that these functions are defined? Am I just confused about how this should work?

.eslintrc.cjs:

```
module.exports = {
  env: {
    browser: true,
    es2021: true,
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      env: {
        node: true,
        "vue/setup-compiler-macros": true,
      },
      files: [".eslintrc.{js,cjs}"],
      parserOptions: {
        sourceType: "script",
      },
    },
  ],
  parser: "vue-eslint-parser",
  parserOptions: {
    parser: "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  },
  extends: [
    "plugin:vue/base",
    "eslint:recommended",
    "plugin:vue/vue3-recommended",
    "plugin:vue/essential",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "plugin:prettier/recommended",
    "eslint-config-prettier",
  ],
  plugins: ["vue", "prettier", "@typescript-eslint"],
  rules: {
    "prettier/prettier": [
      "error",
      {
        endOfLine: "auto",
      },
    ],
    "vue/multi-word-component-names": "off",
    "no-console": "off",
  },
};
```

nuxt.config.js:

```
// https://nuxt.com/docs/api/configuration/nuxt-config
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  css: ["/assets/css/main.css"],
  ssr: false,
  postcss: {
    plugins: {
      tailwindcss: {},
      autoprefixer: {},
    },
  },
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/eslint-module", "@pinia/nuxt"],
  runtimeConfig: {
    public: {
      API_BASE_URL: process.env.API_BASE_URL,
    },
  },
  app: {
    baseURL: "/account",
  },
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eslint with Nuxt3 auto-import](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76803864/eslint-with-nuxt3-auto-import)